# Reading a cell value that contains a formula returns 0.0 when using xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

I try to read a cell value, say E5 and E5 in the excel sheet contains a formula '**=(A29 - A2)**'. I use the following code and it returns me 0.00 instead of the actual value **1.440408**
. Is there a way to solve this? I want to print the correct value. Please help me with this. Thank you.

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook('Test.xlsx')
first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
particular_cell_value = (first_sheet.cell_value(4,4))
print(particular_cell_value)
```

Comment: Seems like in `first_sheet.cell_value(2, 2)` you taking the value of `C3` (or `D4` if arguments of `cell_value` is 1-based) cell?

Comment: I'm sorry I was using (4,4) only. I had changed it for testing and gave it wrong here.

Comment: I wouldn't mind using any excel parser in Python to get a proper result. I tried openpyxl and win32comclient as well but neither of them return the result correctly. :-(

Comment: +1 because i had the same problem a while ago and i've never found a solution

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Excel files store formulas and values independently.**  If the files are saved directly by Excel, then Excel will write both.  However, files generated by other software, such as xlwt, OpenPyXL, and XlsxWriter, *only write the formula*.  This is because there is no guarantee that a third-party package will be able to evaluate Excel's built-in functions exactly the same way that Excel does.  Thus the recommendation (from Microsoft itself, actually) is for third-party packages to write the formula, set the value to zero, and set the global "auto-recalculate" flag on (so if the file is opened in Excel, Excel will go ahead and calculate
all formula results automatically).

XlsxWriter spells it out in its documentation for the [`write_formula()`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#write_formula) method:

> XlsxWriter doesn’t calculate the value of a formula and instead stores the value 0 as the formula result. It then sets a global flag in the XLSX file to say that all formulas and functions should be recalculated when the file is opened. This is the method recommended in the Excel documentation and in general it works fine with spreadsheet applications. However, applications that don’t have a facility to calculate formulas, such as Excel Viewer, or some mobile applications will only display the 0 results.

It then goes on to tell you how to write the value and the formula together if you really want to put a value there.  The value would be whatever you choose, which isn't necessarily the same value that Excel would calculate.  As of this writing, neither xlwt nor OpenPyXL support this feature.

So, having said all that, when it comes to **reading** an Excel file, naturally xlrd is going to pick up 0, unless the result was also written at the same time.  You will notice that xlrd always picks up the correct result when the file was last saved by Excel.  It will also pick up the result (which may or may not be correct) *if you wrote one* using XlsxWriter.

Comment: You saved my day... Thanks!

Comment: opened the file in excel, saved it, now it works! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a cell with a value of zero and an empty cell. To test for this in openpyxl you have to check for TYPE_NULL and also check the value for None, since the TYPE_NULL and TYPE_STRING use the same value 's'. This seems like a bug to me. Perhaps openpyxl will chose a unique value for TYPE_NULL in the future.

```
def use_openpyxl():
    import openpyxl
    print ("Using openpyxl:")
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('cell_formula_test.xlsx')
    ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    for row in ws.rows:
        for cell in row:
            if (cell.data_type == openpyxl.cell.Cell.TYPE_NULL) and (cell.value == None):
                continue
            print ("  %s:%s:%s" % (cell.address, cell.data_type, cell.value))
```

In xlrd the cell_type does have a unique type for empty cells, so the checking is more straight forward.

```
def use_xlrd():
    import xlrd
    print ("Using xlrd:")
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('cell_formula_test.xlsx')
    ws = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    for i in range(ws.nrows):
        for j in range(ws.ncols):
            if ws.cell_type(i, j) != xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY:
                print ("  (%d, %d):%s:%s" % (i, j, ws.cell_type(i, j), ws.cell_value(i, j)))
```

Comment: HI ChipJust, I could never print the cells that contain formulas because, the condition fails at the if condition itself. :-( Since the value it is detecting is 0.00, it doesn't print any damn cell that contains a formula :-(

Comment: Oh, I see. There is a difference between an empty cell and a zero value. You can check that with the cell_type attribute, especially for xlrd. I will rework this example to show this.

Comment: No, the problem here is me cell doesn't have a zero value. My cell has a value like 14.2 or 8.5 or anything. The thing is the sheet is generated by an XlsxWriter and when I try to read it back using xlrd or openpyxl, I face an issue of not being able to read the cell which contains formula. I'm not able to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you post your code and data. Do you still have the issue when you create the spreadsheet manually? Perhaps you could tell me what the above code shows for your data?

Comment: Data: TimeStamp Events Time from Event 1  
20178.55447 Event 1 0  Event 3 from Event 1
20178.64812 Event 2 0.093647  0.1671
20178.67671 Event 3 0.122242  Event N from Event 1
20178.72157 Event 4 0.1671  0.559553
20179.08555 Event 5 0.531082  
20179.10126 Event 6 0.54679  
20179.11403 Event 7 0.559553

Comment: Result from ur code:
Using xlrd:
  (0, 0):1:TimeStamp
  (0, 1):1:Events
  (0, 2):1:Time from Event 1
  (1, 0):2:20178.554472
  (1, 1):1:Event 1
  (1, 2):2:0.0
  (1, 4):1:Event 3 from Event1
  (2, 0):2:20178.648119
  (2, 1):1:Event 2
  (2, 2):2:0.0
  (2, 4):2:0.0
  (3, 0):2:20178.676714
  (3, 1):1:Event 3
  (3, 2):2:0.0
  (3, 4):1:Event N from Event 1
  (4, 0):2:20178.721572
  (4, 1):1:Event 4
  (4, 2):2:0.0
  (4, 4):2:0.0
  (5, 0):2:20179.085554
  (5, 1):1:Event 5
  (5, 2):2:0.0
  (6, 0):2:20179.101262
  (6, 1):1:Event 6
  (6, 2):2:0.0
  (7, 0):2:20179.114025
  (7, 1):1:Event 7
  (7, 2):2:0.0

Comment: The entry from C2 to C8 are   =(A2:A8-A2)

And E3 contains =(A5 - A2) and E5 contains =A8-A2

Comment: I just need the values in E3 and E5. So for the time being I have rectified the problem by changing the way I write to the Excel Sheet. i.e I store the difference in a variable and write it to the file instead of writing a formula to the sheet. This has enabled the xlrd to read the value from the sheet. But it would be better if it already has a permanent solution for the issue or if we can make a permanent solution.

Comment: What does the formula look like in excel after you write it to the sheet using XLRD?

Comment: Nothing different... it looks the same way as I write to the Exel sheet.
E3 -----> (A5-A2)
E5 -----> A8-A2

Comment: Hmm.. I don't know why but for some weird reason it doesn't work for me. Anyways, I have fixed it for the time being by writing the value rather than the formula. Thanks for the help.