# How to use pandas to read formula result which using XlsxWriter to write?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I used pandas to read a excel A and write formula on K column, then saved to a excel B.

```
for row_num in range(1, 18):
    worksheet.write_formula(row_num ,10, '=MID($J%d,LEN(LEFT($J%d,SEARCH(" ",$J%d)+1)),3)' % (row_num+1, row_num+1, row_num+1))
```

I could see the formula that I inserted from excel B and its correct value.

[image]

But when I used pandas to read excel B and print K column, its value became "0", how to solve it? I want to see the calculated value, not formula, not 0.

---

I give a example:

```
#this is about writing formula to excel file
import pandas as pd
cname = []
for i in range(1,5):
    cname.append('=MID("ABCDE",LEN(LEFT("ABCDE",SEARCH("","ABCDE")+1)),3)')
s = pd.DataFrame({'col':cname})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
writer.save()
```

result: 
[image]

Another program to read above excel file:
result: it should be 'BCD', not 0

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I see the formulas of an excel spreadsheet in pandas / python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102674/how-can-i-see-the-formulas-of-an-excel-spreadsheet-in-pandas-python)

Comment: Thank you, but it can't work. What I mean was I used pandas to write formula to cells and read, I can't see the value, only "0".

Comment: How did you use pandas to read excel? It should return calculated value just fine.

Comment: @zipa, please check my example, thank you.

Comment: But I find a related post, maybe it is a issue: [link](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formula-result)

Comment: @SoraLiu - That link from the XlsxWriter documentation is your whole issue. That spells it out nicely. You could also check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24126789/95852) to a similar question.

Comment: You almost definitely need to use Excel itself to calculate those formulas. The usual way to do that with Python these days is [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/).

Comment: @JohnY, thank you for your reply! xlwings seems cool, I will try it later.

Comment: Finally, I decided to transform dataframe to string to fetch substrings. It can replace formula question.